# Change extension icon background using css

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Hello I am trying to remove the default background of toolbar icons when hover in firefox using userChrome.css

```
     .toolbarbutton-icon
     {
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px black, 0 -0.01em 1px 0px #D0D0D0 !important;
        background-color: var(--uc-regular-colour) !important;
        width: 26px !important;
        height: 26px !important;
        padding: 5px !important;
     }
```

This block of code changes the size and color of all toolbar buttons including extension icons

Then I used this block of code to change its color when hover over them

```
     *:hover > .toolbarbutton-icon{
        background-color: green !important;
     }
```

Which changes color of buttons when hover but the extension buttons stays the same.

How can I change it without having to define each extension name or property

Below are some screenshots to demonstrate the issue

[image: hover over settings icon]

[image: hover over private browsing icon]

[image: hover over foxyproxy extension icon]

As you can see except extension button all buttons change color

```
*:hover .toolbarbutton-icon {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Tried this block as well as suggested below, but it hovers on all icons by default, I want each button to change color when hovered over them also when I hover over the extension button It still has the gray color

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will be a problem when you use `>`.

The `>` notation applies only to the immediate children of that element.

Try use:

```css
*:hover .toolbarbutton-icon {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It hovers all buttons by default because parent can be anything, I want it to change when I hover over the specific button

Answer (score 0):

```
.webextension-browser-action:hover > .toolbarbutton-badge-stack .toolbarbutton-icon { background-color: var(--uc-hover-colour) !important;}
```

Apparently after doing some research. Finally found a way to fix it.
The block of codes only works with extensions installed on firefox